# How to customize a spinner with floating text

Tags: android, spinner, android-custom-view

I want to customize `Spinner` with a floating text like in `EditText` with floating label. Please check the reference image below:

[image]

Now I am thinking to put a `TextView` just above `Spinner` so that it looks like in the image. If I am wrong or anybody have different opinion please help me.

**UPDATE**

Solution:   Use following library to use material theme on pre-lollipop 
https://github.com/rey5137/material

Comment: Not including the red+white text right

Comment: may be help you https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner

Comment: I used rey's material library https://github.com/rey5137/material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837938/4230345) to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625620/4230345)...

> I have created a compound `View` component which displays a label above the `Spinner`. The text for the label can be set using XML or in Java.
>
> The component has the key features of a `Spinner` (*not all* of them) as well as looking similar to the `TextInputLayout` component.
>
> I have named it a [`LabelledSpinner`](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/satsuware/usefulviews/LabelledSpinner.java), and it is available as part of my [**UsefulViews**](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews) Android library on GitHub under the [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).
>
> To use it, add the library dependency in your `build.gradle` file:
>
> `compile 'com.satsuware.lib:usefulviews:+'`
>
> Examples of its usage are available at the GitHub repository (both a sample app, and a usage guide).

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal What exactly doesn't work? Open an issue on the GitHub repo or reply to this.